# Solve the equation in positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factoring, integers

Solve the equation in positive  integers  for  $ x,y $

$$ \frac{47}{\sqrt x} \ + \ \frac{43}{\sqrt y} = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2021}}$$
I tried factoring , squaring , putting integer restrictions but didn't seem to go anywhere.
Please provide the way through.

Comment: It has to be significant that $47 \cdot 43=2021$.  What happens when you take reciprocals of both sides?

Comment: Please include your solution attempt in the question, so as to dissuade others from voting to close.

Comment: One solution is $x=y=47\cdot 43 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 2^2.$ [looked for solution where $x=y=t$ on a symbolic calculator. The calculator says it works but I didn't check by hand.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing denominators yields
$$47\sqrt{2021}\sqrt{y}+43\sqrt{2021}\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y},$$
and hence also
$$\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}-43\sqrt{2021}\sqrt{x}-47\sqrt{2021}\sqrt{y}=0.\tag{1}$$
Next note that
$$(\sqrt{x}-47\sqrt{2021})(\sqrt{y}-43\sqrt{2021})=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}-43\sqrt{2021}\sqrt{x}-47\sqrt{2021}\sqrt{y}+43\cdot47\cdot2021,$$
so equation $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$(\sqrt{x}-47\sqrt{2021})(\sqrt{y}-43\sqrt{2021})=43\cdot47\cdot2021=43^2\cdot47^2.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: This is a bit difficult since $x$ is an integer but $\sqrt{x}$ is not necessarily, but we may still get solutions. I know it can easily be bounded now, but that's still a lot of cases. What am I missing?

Comment: @DerekLuna I'm not sure that you're missing something. There is indeed still a lot of work to be done. I would distinguish by the divisibility of $x$ and $y$ by $43$ and $47$. Squaring both sides also helps, as then you're left only with the two square roots $\sqrt{2021x}$ and $\sqrt{2021y}$. But there are multiple approaches from here.

Comment: Thanks! Its now easy